# 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data Issue in admin form when uploading file

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, adminform

I added some extra fields to store_group admin entry, the issue is that i can't upload a image file because i hanven't the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my form when i inspect the HTML code,and Im sure that the issue comes from this, i tried to add it like this but it doesn't work !

**Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/System/Store/Edit/Form.php**

```
protected function _prepareForm(){

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id'        => 'edit_form',
        'action'    => $this->getData('action'),
        'method'    => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' //My add for enctype upload image !important
    ));
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    parent::_prepareForm();

    if (Mage::registry('store_type') == 'group' && Mage::registry('store_action') == "edit")
    {
        $groupModel = Mage::registry('store_data');
        $fieldset = $this->getForm()->getElement('group_fieldset');

        //The extra fields
        ...
        $fieldset->addField('group_storelocator_image_url', 'image', array(
            'name' => 'group[storelocator_image_url]',
            'label' => 'Store Image',
            'required' => false,
            'note' => $groupModel->getStorelocatorImageUrl() != NULL ? "<a href=\"" . Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $groupModel->getStorelocatorImageUrl() . "\" target=\"_blank\" ><img src=\"" . Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $groupModel->getStorelocatorImageUrl() . "\" width=\"60\" /><br />" . $groupModel->getStorelocatorImageUrl() . "</a>" : "",
            'disabled' => $groupModel->isReadOnly(),
        ));
    }
    return $this;
}
```

**Namespace/Module/ModuleController.php**

```
class Namespace_Module_ModuleController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function saveAction()
    {
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            if (isset($_FILES['storelocator_image_url']['name']) && $_FILES['storelocator_image_url']['name'] != '') {
                try {
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . 'store' . DS;  //desitnation directory in store folder
                    $fname = $_FILES['storelocator_image_url']['name']; //file name
                    $fullname = $path . $fname;
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('storelocator_image_url'); //load class
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png')); //Allowed extension for file
                    $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true); //for creating the directory if not exists
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $uploader->save($path, $fname);
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $fileType = "Invalid file format";
                }
            }
        }
        if ($fileType == "Invalid file format") {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('foundation')->__($fname . " Invalid file format"));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if you use `return parent::_prepareForm();` instead of `return $this` in Form.php ?

Comment: I tried it and it tells me an error, addField() on null

Answer (score 0):

In your `Form.php` Try below code

```
protected function _prepareForm(){

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id'        => 'edit_form',
        'action'    => $this->getData('action'),
        'method'    => 'post',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data' //My add for enctype upload image !important
    ));


    if (Mage::registry('store_type') == 'group' && Mage::registry('store_action') == "edit")
    {
        $groupModel = Mage::registry('store_data');
        $fieldset = $this->getForm()->getElement('group_fieldset');

        //The extra fields
        ...
        $fieldset->addField('group_storelocator_image_url', 'image', array(
            'name' => 'group[storelocator_image_url]',
            'label' => 'Store Image',
            'required' => false,
            'note' => $groupModel->getStorelocatorImageUrl() != NULL ? "<a href=\"" . Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $groupModel->getStorelocatorImageUrl() . "\" target=\"_blank\" ><img src=\"" . Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . $groupModel->getStorelocatorImageUrl() . "\" width=\"60\" /><br />" . $groupModel->getStorelocatorImageUrl() . "</a>" : "",
            'disabled' => $groupModel->isReadOnly(),
        ));
    }
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);
    return parent::_prepareForm();

}
```

Comment: Nop, i have an error in `$fieldset = $this->getForm()->getElement('group_fieldset');` i changed `$this` with `$form` and i'll have another error : `Call to a member function addField() on null in`